# Adding options in overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

can someone explain why the 2nd item is not being added to the overflow menu in the actionbar? The **settings** displays correctly, and **profile** displays if I set the `showAsAction` to `always`, but I would rather have **profile** appear in the overflow menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:Molo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/settings"
          Molo:showAsAction="always" /> 

    <item android:id="@+id/action_profile"
        android:title="@string/action_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/user"
        Molo:showAsAction="never"/> 
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:showAsAction` mapped to the same value as `Molo:showAsAction`, as that should help on newer devices.

Comment: Nope, not working either. Maybe I should add that the overflow menu isn't even being created. Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: @CodeVader: Does your device have a MENU button? If so, that's your trigger for the overflow. The "..." will appear on all Android 4.4+ devices plus on older devices that do not have a MENU button.

Answer (score 0):

just removed the Molo:showAsAction="never" ,Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/settings"
      Molo:showAsAction="always" /> 

<item android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:title="@string/action_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/user" />
```